# Solving SIR model differential equation system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve this ode system for a few days now and I just can't figure out what to do. $$S'=uk-bSI-uS$$ $$I'=bSI-yI-uI-aI$$ $$R'=yI-uR$$

I think I should be able to decouple the first two equations and then solve the third when I know I(t) but I can't figure out how to decouple them into the 2x2 system.

note: u,k,b,y,a are constants

Comment: You can decouple but it leaves you with a real ugly nonlinear 2nd order diff equation in $S$. Also if you add all the equations together you almost get something interesting in terms of $(S+I+R)$, if only $a=0$!

Answer (score 1):

Generally in SIR models, it is very hard to get explicit solutions for the dependant variables when $S+I+R=N$ is not constant (which is your case). Instead what some people do is study the equilibria and look at the solutions near the equilibria. That is, ignoring the R equation, an obvious equilibrium for $(S,I)$ is $(k,0)$. Now, we assume the system is close to equilibrium, so we can neglect nonlinear terms. So we consider, 
$$S'\approx uk-uS$$
$$I'\approx -(y+u+a)I,$$ 
which can give an approximate solution near the first equilibrium. 
For the other equilibrium we can do a change of variables that shift the system and repeat.

Comment: If we just take the $2\times 2$ system with $\dot{S}$ and $\dot{I}$ as expressed in the question, I don't see as to how $(0,0)$ would given an equilibrium point. If we let $S=0=I$, then $\dot{S}=\mu K\neq 0$.

Comment: @RebeccaHardenbrook You are correct, silly mistake. Of course, this means we can not really neglect the nonlinear term until we shift the S variable.